# Need to divide variable with specific numbers in R

Tags: r

I have an issue with the division of variables with the responding values

Let's say I have one dataframe with the following data:

```
ID    Year    V1   V2
1     2011    10   34
1     2012    20   35
2     2011    30   20
2     2012    35   14
3     2011    19   16
3     2012    75   17
```

And also I have another dataframe with the following values:

```
Year    index
2011    5
2012    12
```

The expected output is that I want to divide each value with the index of respective year, so that it looks like:

```
ID    Year    V1      V2
1     2011    10/5    34/5
1     2012    20/12   35/12
2     2011    30/5    20/5
2     2012    35/12   14/12
3     2011    19/5    16/5
3     2012    75/12   17/12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do a join with `data.table` and divide

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, c('V1', 'V2') := .(V1/index, V2/index), 
    on = .(Year), by = .EACHI]
```

-output

```
df1
#   ID Year       V1       V2
#1:  1 2011 2.000000 6.800000
#2:  1 2012 1.666667 2.916667
#3:  2 2011 6.000000 4.000000
#4:  2 2012 2.916667 1.166667
#5:  3 2011 3.800000 3.200000
#6:  3 2012 6.250000 1.416667
```

---

Or using `base R` with `merge`

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'Year', all.x = TRUE),
      V1 = V1/index, V2 = V2/index)[names(df1)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Year = c(2011L, 
2012L, 2011L, 2012L, 2011L, 2012L), V1 = c(10, 20, 30, 35, 19, 
75), V2 = c(34, 35, 20, 14, 16, 17)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
      class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Year = 2011:2012, index = c(5L, 12L)), 
  class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Is there any other base R approach, since I do not really understand the context of *data.table* package. Furthermore, this way do not work with my real dataset, since I do not know how to specify needed variables to be divided

Comment: @WadimiLchuk I updated the post with `merge` from `base R`

Comment: May I ask one more question. If I need to divide more than 2 variables, for example, 9 out of 12, how can I select and divide all except 3?

Comment: @WadimiLchuk you can have the names subset or with index i.e. `nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), c("ID", "Year")); setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1):=  lapply(mget(nm1), `/`, index), 
     on = .(Year), by = .EACHI]` with `data.table`

Comment: @WadimiLchuk or using `base R` `out <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'Year', all.x = TRUE); out[nm1] <- lapply(out[nm1], `/`, out$index)`. The backquotes are wrapped on the `/`

Answer (score 1):

There's also a tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble(ID = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), Year = c("2011", "2012", "2011", "2012", "2011", "2012"), V1 = c(10, 20, 30, 35, 19, 75),
       V2 = c(34, 35, 20, 14, 16, 17))

divisors <- tibble(Year = c("2011", "2012"), index = c(5, 12))

data %>%
  left_join(divisors, by = "Year") %>%
  mutate(V1 = V1/index, V2 = V2/index) %>%
  select(-index)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID    Year     V1    V2
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1     2011   2     6.8 
2 1     2012   1.67  2.92
3 2     2011   6     4   
4 2     2012   2.92  1.17
5 3     2011   3.8   3.2 
6 3     2012   6.25  1.42
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `match`

```
df1[c("V1", "V2")] <- df1[c("V1", "V2")] / df2$index[match(df1$Year, df2$Year)]
```

gives

```
> df1
  ID Year       V1       V2
1  1 2011 2.000000 6.800000
2  1 2012 1.666667 2.916667
3  2 2011 6.000000 4.000000
4  2 2012 2.916667 1.166667
5  3 2011 3.800000 3.200000
6  3 2012 6.250000 1.416667
```